# Eclipse IDE, Blue Scope WTF

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Can someone please explain to me what is this feature called and how do I turn it off?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the range indicator - a useful feature for highlighting the scope of classes and methods.

To switch off you can use

```
Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors
```

Unclick "Show range indicator" checkbox

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know what to call it so i didn't know where to look for it. I'm sure somebody worked really hard to get it there... but I just don't want it. Many thanks again!